# RegEx for not matching items in a quote

Tags: sql, regex

So I am trying to figure out a Regular Expression and am having some issues. What I want to find (match) is all of the SQL parameters in a large script file, but NOT match items in single quotes (such as email addresses).  For example:

```
INSERT INTO [User]
(
   [UserGuid], [CompanyGuid], [Name], [EmailAddress]
) VALUES (
   @UserGuid1, @CompanyGuid, 'Jason', 'jason@jason.com'
)
```

With `@UserGuid1` and `@CompanyGuid` matching, but not @jason matching.  I have been using this RegEx:

```
(@+[\w]+)
```

But it matches the email address, so I tried to do a negative look ahead/behind like this:

```
(?<!')[\W](@+[\w]+)[\W](?!')
```

but it is matching the '(' in the following example:

```
INSERT INTO [User] ([UserGuid]) VALUES (@UserGuid1)
```

Anyone have an idea what I am missing here?  Something that can say: "anything that is NOT in a quote set?".  Also, it is safe to assume balanced quote sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you try the following?

```
(?<=\W)(@\w+)
```

basically it makes sure that the captured value preceded by a non-word character, you can add look-ahead too but it's kinda redundant because `+` is greedy and will match until non-word anyway.

the following will insure that in `INSERT INTO [User] ([UserGuid]) VALUES ('@UserGuid1')` nothing is matched:

```
(?<![\w'])(@\w+)
```

Comment: I don't think that would work, since there is no space before the parameter in the second example text.

Comment: fixed now (overenginneering begets user frustration, jeff)

Comment: OK, that seems to work, though it will match items like '@something' that aren't e-mail addresses, but are quoted inputs. Adding the lookahead/behinds for quotes would help, like so:

(?<=\W)(?<!')(@\w+)(?!')

Comment: quote is a non-word, your look-behinds seem to be redundant

Comment: No, it is necessary. What my regex is saying is that the match must be preceded by any non-word EXCEPT a single quote. This is to prevent something like ('@text') from being matched. If I understood look-behinds a bit better, I could probably condense it further, but specifying that the preceding character not be a quote is definitely necessary.

Comment: so it must not be preceded by word or a quote in other words, `(?<![\w'])`. Right?

Comment: (?<=\W)(@\w+) fails on INSERT INTO [User] ([UserGuid]) VALUES ('@UserGuid1').

Comment: Please edit the answer to include the <code>(?<![\w'])</code> and I will mark this as answer (and delete this comment and my above one) as I *THINK* SilentGhost was first, but I upvoted both.

Answer (score 1):

(@+[^']+) should help. The [^' ,] will match anything except a single quote, space or comma. You may need to add a few more characters, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`(?<=[^\w'])(@\w+)(?!')`

This specifies that each match must be preceded by a non-word character (except for single quotes), then have an @ sign and a word, and not followed by another single quote.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what my comment said

Comment: I'm not about to get into an internet argument, but if you test it, you'll see that I'm right.

I'm using this tester:

http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm saying that effectively the same thing was posted in the comment before your answer. Additionally, OP writes that *it is safe to assume balanced quote sets*, so the look-ahead check is again redundant.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I didn't see your last comment because it was the sixth one and was hidden, and I went ahead and looked it up. No worries :-)

Good point, though, on the look-ahead.